# Сравнение двух датафреймов с большим количеством столбцов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть два датафрейма с одинаковыми названиями столбцов, но с разными значениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сравнить значения в столбцах с одинаковым названием в этих двух датафреймах и создать новый датафрейм NewDf, в котором будет 1 если portfolio_experiment > _10days_roll и 0 - если меньше.

Я пробовал через:

```py
mergedStuff = pd.merge(portfolio_experiment, _10days_roll, on=['date'], how='inner')
mergedStuff.tail()
```

Получил в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу понять как обработать и сравнить например DOCU_x с DOCU_y и так по всем столбцам ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Pandas переопределены операторы сравнения для DataFrame'ов - воспользуйтесь ими.

Пример:

```
In [207]: d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=list("abc"))

In [208]: d2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,2,1], [7,8,4], [1,2,9]], columns=list("abc"))

In [209]: d1
Out[209]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [210]: d2
Out[210]:
   a  b  c
0  2  2  1
1  7  8  4
2  1  2  9

In [211]: d1 < d2
Out[211]:
       a      b      c
0   True  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False

In [212]: (d1 < d2).astype("int8")
Out[212]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  0  0
```